# Complex logic to implement the sum of previous balance with the current balance

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue in implementing the cumulative sum of previous balance with the new balance please help. The Input is below

| Date | Id | Input | Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230301 | 3 | 1000 | 200 |
| 20230302 | 3 | null | 100 |
| 20230303 | 3 | 500 | 100 |

Output Expected

| Date | Id | Input | Spent | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230301 | 3 | 1000 | 200 | 800 |
| 20230302 | 3 | null | 100 | 700 |
| 20230303 | 3 | 500 | 100 | 1100 |

Since the Date '20230303' had new input the previous balance should be added with the new input to calculate the Output. Please Advise

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What language do you want this solution in, Python or SQL?  YOu've tagged multiple technologies here, but i've no idea which you want. If you're using SQL, what's wrong with a windowed `SUM`?

Comment: All it seems you want here is a cumulative `SUM` of `Input - Spent`; what is the difficulty you are having here?

Comment: I'm looking it in pyspark but should be fine if i get the SQL. Sum(Input-Spent) over a window function doesn't work as Row3 should be sum (previous output + new Input)

Comment: Not sure what you mean it wouldn't work. `(1000 + 500) - (200 + 100 + 100) = 1000 - 200 -100 + 500 - 100 = 1100` which is the value you want.

Comment: @Larnu, If you closely check the Expected output table For '20230302' Output value is 700, When Caluclating the next output for '20230303' it should be 700+500(Input) - 100 = 1100

Comment: I have, and I don't see the problem... You want a cumulative `SUM`, and a cumulative `SUM` gives you the answer, as demonstrated.

Comment: `700+500(Input) - 100 = 1100 = (1000 {prior input} - (200 + 100) {prior Spents}) + 500 {Current Input) - 100 {current spent}` It's still a cumulative `SUM`. I suggest you [edit] your question to demonstrate your attempt with a cumulative `SUM`  (see the linked duplicate) and explain why it doesn't work.